# Most efficient way of hooking lower voltage component up to higher voltage supply

Tags: batteries, resistors, motor

I want to hook up a 22.2 V motor up to a 28 V supply. Is there a more efficient way of doing this other than using a resistor and dissipating the extra energy in heat?

Comment: You mean like a DC/DC (buck) converter?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Please provide more detail about the motor - it is very unusual for a motor to be specified at an unusual voltage and never to 3 significant figures - they can always accept a fairly wide range of voltages, it may even include 28v if it is a nominal 24 volt motor.  A 24v electrical system will probably run at 28v.  A car system is referred to as 12v but in fact is about 14v when running.

Comment: "a 22.2 V motor" - you mean a motor that is designed to run on a 6 cell Lithium battery? _Which_ motor?

Comment: Most efficient in what terms? Energy consumed? Torque generated? Price of components?

Answer (score 1):

Without information about the type of motor, I will assume it is a plain old brushed DC motor.

The simplest (yet still efficient) thing to do would be to apply a PWM to it with 80% duty cycle.

Since you don't specify the motor current, the choice of MOSFET and other parts is up to you...